# Kivy image not loading from source

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to add a Image widget to a view

```
img = Image(source=image_path)
self.image_view.add_widget(img)
```

Unfortunate if the image is not loaded in the KV file the app will just stop with 
`Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`.

If I add the image to the kv file

```
    Image:
        source: 'images/circle.png'
```

and then add it as stated above it works. But I don't want to add it in the kv file, better say I don't want this image to show anywhere except when I need it. What is the right way to load the image?

`Kivy==1.11.1`

Comment: Please post a [mcve].